# Google passport authentication error: Code was already redeemed

Tags: node.js, google-app-engine, passport.js, google-signin, passport-google-oauth2

I'm getting problem regarding google passport login.

After successful google authentication the screen keeps loading and is unable to redirect to the website again. I'm able to trace the google auth callback in the logs but somehow I just cant catch it in the server application. My code for the authentication and callback is correct as it works fine in the localhost and other cloud platform(openshift) where I tried hosting my node 
application.

this is the error i get in the `/auth/google/callback` :

```
TokenError: Code was already redeemed.
       at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:329:12)
       at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:376:16)
       at /app/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:166:45
       at /app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
       at passBackControl (/app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
       at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> /app/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
       at emitNone (events.js:111:20) at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1055:12)
       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
```

someone please help resolving this issue I have tried almost everything suggested in many links like

1. https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-google-oauth/issues/82
2. [Google Oauth giving code redeemed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167336/google-oauth-giving-code-redeemed-error)

but no success so far.

Comment: I would like to see your code anyway. Don't forget to edit all the private data out.

Comment: hey nvm i found a workaround. What i have realized is that the login doesnt give a callback in the production mode but works just fine in the dev mode. So i ran the dev mode in the production using forever.js but i'd still like to know y the heck it doesnt work in production.

Comment: what do you mean by that?

Comment: Sorry @Marshall, I have deleted my previous comments as they are not relevant to your question.