# Unable to reach to the redirecting URL while using passport-google-oauth20

Tags: node.js, oauth-2.0, google-oauth

I just started to learn OAuth. I am using passport-google-oauth20 with node.js. Below is the code from the passport-setup.js file of my project.

```
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20');
const keys = require('./keys')

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy({
        //options for google strategy
        callbackURL:'https://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect',
        clientID:keys.google.clientID,
        clientSecret:keys.google.clientSecret
    }, function(){
        //passport callback function
})
);
```

Code from the auth-route.js file of my project

```
const router = require('express').Router();
const passport = require('passport');

//auth login
router.get('/login', function(req,res){
    res.render('login');
});

//auth logout
router.get('/logout', function(req,res){
    //have to handle with passport
    res.send('Logging out');
});

//auth with google
router.get('/google', passport.authenticate('google',{
    scope:['profile']
}));

//callback route for google
router.get('/google/redirect', passport.authenticate('google'), 
    function(req,res){
        res.send('You logged in');
});

module.exports = router;
```

Can refer to full code @ https://github.com/Ayush-Porwal/OAuth-learning.git

I am trouble with redirect URL. When callbackURL holds the value of "https://localhost:3000/auth/google/redirect", then browser directs me to OAuth consent screen. However, after when I  try logging in, the browser(chrome) gives me an error/message as shown in the screenshot.[image]

while on Firefox, the message is as shown(adding only because of error messages are different )

[image]

And when callbackURL hold the value of "/auth/google/redirect"(I think both values should give same results). The browser gives the error as

[image]

Here is the screenshot for the URI's that I entered in my app on google developer's website.

[image]

I tried several things like changing the code a little etc but I'm not able to realize where the problem is arising. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

The process is incomplete. I have now completed my project and I have written an answer regarding the same. Please follow up from here to my answer on [Google Oauth giving code redeemed error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31167336/google-oauth-giving-code-redeemed-error/51028404#51028404)

Comment: You could post that answer here , it would be helpful.